# How do I replicate Curl POST with POST Man or ARC

Tags: curl, postman, rest-client

```
curl -X POST -vku user@domain.com:redacted   `"https://api.domain.com/api/PWWebService/api/v0/user/{user}/externallyAuthenticate`"
```

where {user} is a placeholder for the username.

Payload sample:

> ExternallyAuthenticateDTOV0{"RolesUser":"ix:identifier2:0002290(domain)","serviceProvider":"ix:name:SomeThingOver", "encounter":"435457"}

I am able to set the POST URL and PayLoad , but not sure where to set the VKU User.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Authorization tab for your request in POSTMAN. The drop down should contain the Authentication mechanism used and will prompt for specific details for what you select.

[POSTMAN Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Nn1.png)